# Javascript - Loading images causes things to randomly be undefined

Tags: javascript

Well this is a strange one for me.
I'm moving my game from ASCII to tile graphics and I have a problem.
After setting up an image pre-loader I get errors telling me that various stuff is undefined.
Here is the image loading function:

```
function preload(){
        characterImage = new Image();
        characterImage.src = "images/character.png";

        groundImage = new Image();
        groundImage.src = "images/ground.png";

        wallImage = new Image();
        wallImage.src = "images/wall.png";

        doorImage = new Image();
        doorImage.src = "images/door.png";

        windowImage = new Image();
        windowImage.src = "images/window.png";

        creatureImage = new Image();
        creatureImage.src = "images/creature.png";

        stairImage = new Image();
        stairImage.src = "images/stairs.png";

        nullImage = new Image();
        nullImage.src = "images/null.png";
    }
```

Other than that I did not touch anything other than

```
<body id="body" onload="preload();">
```

Anyone have any idea what's happening here?

EDIT: I've found the problem, it's that the images aren't loaded before the main script executes. duh.

Comment: What "various stuff" is undefined?  If you mean that the `Image`s you have, they may not be loaded yet.  You'll need to attach to their `onImageLoad`s a function to let you know when they are done loading.

Comment: Need...more...code :)

Answer (score 0):

Onload only fires after everything is loaded (including images)
- so preloading at that point seems.. silly?

Either simply add them to the HTML, and start the game in the onload event
OR
Execute the preload function in < head > and count the number of loaded images by adding:

```
imageX.onload = function(){ if (++number==total) startGame() }
```

to each of them (number=0 and total=7 being global variables)

This assumes nothing else needs to be loaded.. A combination may be needed..

Answer (score -1):

```
<body  onload="preload();" >
```

this means that when the body is loaded, the brower will executes the preload();

Comment: This appears to only be restating code which was provided by the question author.